# Cochrane-Orcutt procedure with higher-order differencing

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, autocorrelation

I have a set of monthly time series data, and I would like to fit regression models with exogenous variables (price) to a response (sales volume).  The errors are surely autocorrelated, and I need a way to account for this.

I am aware of the Cochrane-Orcutt procedure, and it seems there's a lot of wisdom there.

https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat501/lesson/t/t.2/t.2.4-examples-applying-cochrane-orcutt-procedure

However, I'm concerned that this method only uses only a first-order differencing.

1. There is noise in the data, and a first-order differencing ignores information at higher-order lags.  There's a reason why exponential smoothing is such an effective forecasting method - because it incorporates higher order lags in a smoothed way.
2. There is likely a lag between the relationship of the exogenous variable and the response.  If there is, say a 1 or 2 month lag, doesn't that destroy the relationship between first-order differenced variables?

I would appreciate any guidance on how to tackle this problem :)

Is there a more sophisticated version of Cochrane-Orcutt that includes a sort of exponential smoothing of higher-order lags?  Is there a package for this?  Can I hack it myself?

Do I need to go to time series model that can handle exogenous variables?  The problem with this is that I actually have many time series in a sort of grouping & hierarchy, and I was hoping to fit a mixed effects model on the Cochrane-Orcutt-transformed data.

I am aware of packages `lme4`, `glmmTMB`, `brms` that allow for autocorrelated errors in mixed effects models.  Is this the sort of solution I should pursue?  Unfortunately, most of these also only allow for an AR(1) correlation structure to the errors.

Comment: There's an extension of [Prais-Winsten](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/501495) to AR(2) by [Beach & MacKinnon (1978)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-4076(78)90068-4), but even this "minor" generalization makes the likelihood very complicated. Have you thought about [Newey-West correction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/226966) to the covariance matrix?

Comment: There have been a few threads on residual correlation lately. Check out `nlme` in R - it has a number of covariance patterns it can accommodate. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/633436/beyond-ar1-as-a-covariance-structure-for-mixed-models-with-repeated-measures